# Possible compiler bug while reading file and outputting contents

Tags: c++, gcc

While trying to help a friend with a problem with his code, I encountered a very weird bug when compiling the following code with GCC.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream classes("classes.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::string txt = ".txt";
    while (std::getline(classes, line)) {
        std::cout << "[-]: " << line << "," << txt << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`classes.txt` contains the following:

```
CSC1
CSC2
CSC46
CSC151
MTH121
```

When **compiled with Clang or MSVC**, the output is as follows:

```
[-]: CSC1,.txt
[-]: CSC2,.txt
[-]: CSC46,.txt
[-]: CSC151,.txt
[-]: MTH121,.txt
```

But, when **compiled with GCC**, this is what the code outputs:

```
,.txtCSC1
,.txtCSC2
,.txtCSC46
,.txtCSC151
[-]: MTH121,.txt
```

I cannot make sense of whats happening here. Can anyone explain this?

Image with GCC version and output:
[image]

Comment: Are you running clang on the same OS / input file?

Comment: In the Ubuntu version check that the text file you're opening doesn't contain `\r\n` line endings. Windows compilers will translate them to `\n` but gcc/linux will not, so it outputs the carriage return appearing to overwrite part of the line

Comment: Also, try `./a.out | cat -v`. Compiler bug, my posterior.

Comment: Compilers certainly can and do have bugs, but the vast majority of issues like the one you describe are *not* compiler bugs.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a compiler bug. You are running into line-ending differences between operating systems. My magic ball tells me that if you run `dos2unix classes.txt`, the problem will go away. Similarly, `cat -v classes.txt` should output something similar to the following:

```
CSC1^M
CSC2^M
CSC46^M
CSC151^M
MTH121^M
```

Here, the `^M` denotes `\r\n`. This is known as a CRLF or "carriage return line feed". On Linux when the carriage return is encountered, it instructs the terminal to go back to the beginning of the line. This results in `.txt` overwriting whatever you had output previously.

**N.B** if you are running Clang on an Apple system, which I'm guessing you are, certain versions of Mac use `\r`, but not `\r\n` or `\n`..

Comment: The `\r` line endings from older versions of MacOS are unlikely be an issue (but it's worth mentioning).